# ipad showing my sprite images incorrectly

Tags: css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari, css-sprites

I'm wondering if this is something somewhat simple, but I'm having a problem ONLY on iPad with my sprited images.  I have an  tag that I use a sprite for to display an image of a star (similar to gmail or picasa) to indicate a favorite.  On every other browser (including safari) on a computer, it's all completely fine.

The problem is on an iPad, it's showing more of the sprite than it should and it looks strange.  What's even stranger is that this image is repeated several times and it doesn't seem to happen consistently.

Is this some sort of zoom issue or viewport setting problem specifically for iPad?  It's driving me crazy, and anything I do to fix it cuts off some of the image and ruins the normal browser look.

Here's an example of what I mean since I can't put up the page I'm currently working on.
On this site I've worked on in the past, the viewing options look strange on an iPad:
http://demo.qlikview.com/index.aspx?section=Life
For example the "Download" viewing option looks different on the FEMA app than on the Kick It app so it doesn't even appear to be consistent.

[image: here's a screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Unless this is an issue known to someone, I suspect you'll need to provide some kind of code or test case.

Comment: i don't think he need to show some code. This is a browser scaling problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the iPad scales your page.

The size of your element where the sprite is used is scaled and the sprite image to. But it seems not to behave precisely.

The same thing happens when you zoom out in safari. This is because an image is not scaled the same way in the browser then a dom element. A dom element is rendered as vector object. So when you zoom in or out, the lines keep sharp. When you do the same with a bitmap. It gets blurry and the browser need to guess how the image would look like smaller or bigger.

You have two options:

1. use more space between the sprites.
2. use EMs and not Pixels in your CSS

PS: Don't use !important in your css

Comment: great insight, thanks.  Why would using EMs help in particular?

Comment: because safari seams to handle resizing better with EMs. You could try specifying the CSS3 Background-size in percent. This could help to.

Comment: The `!important` statement has it's place in css when used appropriately. Blindly instructing someone not to use it is irresponsible.

Answer (score 2):

Like meo pointed out, best option would be to **leave space between the sprites**.

There is also one last thing you can do, which is **not to let the user zoom the web page** by putting the following line in your  tag. It would look the exact same as you view in the browser, which is pretty neat if you have loads of elements messed up in the iPad because of the sprite issue.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for leave space between the sprites, this issue has cropped up in other browsers too *cough*IE*cough*

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix for this is to put an outline around your spite with the border color the same as the parent container's background color. The outline is outside you element and does not effect layout. What you see is a problem mobile Webkit has when it scales down images with background color or background images, they bleed out of their container. The outline will sit on top of that and cover it.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is just define separate images (non-sprited) for iPad users.  I know it doesn't load as quickly as you're hoping for with sprited images, but I feel it's a price they have to pay.  What I do is have individual images on the server with @media in your stylesheet to define different images for iPad browsers.  A quick review of how to use @media for iPad can be found at:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well. I've been leaving extra space between my sprites since I first noticed the iPad imperfections. However, my current project involved sprites *and* another element with CSS3 transforms. The combination made the sprites blurry, with strange clipping around the edges. I actually found a fix over at [No more jagged edges in iOS](http://www.css-101.org/articles/-webkit-transform-rotate-and-anti-aliasing/rotate-creates-jagged-border-image.php). Try applying the following CSS to your sprites:

```
/* IOS fix for incorrectly scaled sprites */
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
background-clip:padding-box;
```

Those few lines worked magic in my project. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: Also, the page [CSS3 Animations: the Hiccups and Bugs You’ll Want to Avoid](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid/) had many other useful iOS fixes for CSS3 transformations.